# Not always dismissing keyboard when touching outside of textfield

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have touches method but it works only when i click on some areas of the view not everywhere.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];// this will do the trick
}
```

how can I fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: can you check if no other views are overlaping and receiving your touch events?

Comment: I have a scrollview,that probably receives touchesBegan in other areas of the view. so how Can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, try with below code & check:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
//Get touch point
CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:self.view];

//Hide keyBoard
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```